# Как собрать плагин для Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, компиляция

Нашел по [данному](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734967/installing-jsdt-jquery-plugin-in-eclipse-kepler-4-3) топику инструкцию:

1. Download source code from
   https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/source/default/source
   or https://github.com/Nodeclipse/jsdt-jquery
2. Unzip and maven build the source code
3. In eclipse Help->Install New
   Software->Add...->Archive...->/location_to_source_directory/org.eclipselabs.jsdt.updatesite/target/org.eclipselabs.jsdt.updatesite-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip
4. Give name -> Ok

Пункты 1,3,4 понятны.
А вот пункт 2 для меня как не Java программиста непонятен.
Какую версию Eclipse использовать, как компилировать под конкретную версию и т.д. непонятно.
Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

По вашей второй ссылке слева внизу есть кнопка "Install". Не пробовали её нажимать? Интересно зачем не программисту потребовался плагин для эклипс...

Comment: Я не Java программист, но я PHP, .NET, JS, LUA, VBA, Perl программист )

Comment: если вы посмотрите внимательнее, то обнаружите что это отголоски прошлых 5ти лет.... эта ссылка ведет на документацию о том как юзать инсталятор маркетплейса, но на маркете такого компонента нету! Если бы он там был, я бы его уже поставил давно... И ссылка рядом с кнопкой install нерабочая.

Comment: Извините, внимательнее не смотрел. В таком случае боюсь, что без программиста Java вам не справиться. Если вкратце - вам нужно установить и настроить JDK и maven. Желательно ознакомится с инструкцией [Building a Project with Maven](http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html). Собрать плагин с помощью maven. Это уже должно быть не сложно, т.к. необходимый для сборки проекта файл pom.xml у вас уже есть. Останется только проинсталлировать получившийся плагин в ваш Eclipse.